# PuTTY not showing /etc/nologin message

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty

I have blocked non-root access to a Scientific Linux server by setting `/etc/nologin`.  When I try to log in from a Linux terminal, the contents of the `/etc/nologin` are displayed, as expected.  However, when I use PuTTY to access the server from a Windows machine, a pop-up window appears with the message `Server unexpectedly closed network connection`.  I have the setting `Close window on exit` set to never.

Does anyone know how to get PuTTY to display the contents of `/etc/nologin`?

Comment: How are you connecting with PuTTY? SSH or Telnet?

Comment: Access is only via SSH.

Comment: it looks like you're connection get either cut of or rejected from your server did you take a look at puttys connection log to see what exactly happend - maybe you need to increase Log Level to Debug to see more

Comment: As I wrote, the server **should** close the connection, because I have set it up to do exactly that.  In PuTTY's log I can see that the `/etc/nologin` text is received and is followed immediately by the message "Server unexpectedly closed".  Somehow the pop-up with the error message seems to prevent the `/etc/nologin` text from being appearing in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem of getting PuTTY to display a message when login via SSH is blocked.  However, instead of setting `/etc/nologin`, I added the following to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match User *,!alice,!bob,!carol,!root
   Banner /root/etc/nologin
   ForceCommand echo
```

As well as PuTTY actually showing the banner, this has the added advantage that I can allow selective access for some users.

Comment: This however makes the message appear twice if I SSH from an open terminal (for example an already logged in PuTTY-session)

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you have incorrectly set the shell to the message (ie /etc/nologin) - what you want is to set the shell to /usr/sbin/nologin - which is a program which will run and, I assume, display the contents of /etc/nologin

Comment: I haven't changed the shell.  From 'man 5 nologin':

   "If the file /etc/nologin exists, login(1) will allow access only to root.
   Other users will be shown the contents of this file and their logins will
   be refused."

As I said, everything works as expected when I try to log in from a Linux
terminal.